# What are the random variables in Universal Hash Function?

Tags: hash, universal-hash

Universal hash function is defined as follow:

$f_{(k_0,k_1)}(x) = (k_0\cdot x + k_1) \mod p$, where $p$ is prime

In Wikipedia, it is mentioned that the above function is pairwise independent. Pairwise independence is defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_independence)

I wonder what are the random variables in $f$ and what pairwise independence means here.

Comment: Could you give the link for the definition?

Comment: @kelalaka the link is in the text, but here is in plain https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_independence

Comment: This is in [Universal_hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing) . Carter and Wegman; $h_{a,b}(x) = ((a \cdot x +b) \bmod p) \bmod m $  where $a , b$ are *randomly chosen* integers modulo $p$ with $a \neq 0$.

Comment: please include the definition in the question itself for improved readability. after all you are asking others to put in an effort to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

The random variables are $k_0$ and $k_1$, typically taken to be uniformly distributed in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ in this context.

(Sometimes we take $k_0$ to be uniform in $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times$ instead, *i.e.* exclude $k_0 = 0$, but as long as $p \gg 2^{100}$ this is not important.)

Comment: Thanks! Why do not you consider the $x$ as a random variable?

Comment: The defining property of a universal hash family is a bound on the collision probability $\Pr[H(x) = H(y)]$ for _all_ $x \ne y$.  That is, there's a _for all_ quantifier on $x$ and $y$, but a _probability_ quantifier on the hash function $H$ (or, equivalently, over the internal parameters $k_0$ and $k_1$).

Comment: So, why $f_{(k_0,k_1)}(x) = (k_0\cdot x + k_1) \mod p$ is a pairwise independent but $f_{(k_0,k_1)}(x) = (k_0\cdot x \cdot k_1)$ is not?

Comment: @Reza $f_{(k_0,k_1)}(x) = (k_0 \cdot x \cdot k_1) \bmod p$ is equivalent to $g_{k_0\cdot k_1}$ where $g_k(x) = k\cdot x \bmod p$.  Suppose you know what $g_k(x)$ is; can you deduce, then, what $g_k(y)$ is?  If you can, is it possible for $g$ to be pairwise independent?  (Remember what the definition of pairwise independence is!)